# Flutter Android Studio does not show errors before run in only one project of mine "no error or warnings"

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: (value) {
                        Pattern pattern = r'^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$';
                        RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern); //check for asking
                        if (value.isEmpty)
                          return 'required*';
                        else if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
                          return 'Invalid username';
                        else
                          return null
                      },
                        onChanged:(value) {
                        if (formKey.currentState.validate())
                        setState(() {
                          username=value;
                        });},
                      onSaved: (value) => setState(() => username = value),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
                          ),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          hintText: 'User Name',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey)))
                ),
```

Comment: `return null ` where is `;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap it with Form?

to me i did mine usually like this

Put this to another dart file.

```
String password(String value){
String pattern = r'^.{6,}[A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  if(!regExp.hasMatch(value)) return 'Password must be at least 6 characters';
  else return null;
}
```

then call this to your form text field note wrap textformfield a form

```
   final GlobalKey<FormState> _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
     Form(
     key: _form,
     child: Column(
     children: [
      TextFormField(
            style: TextStyle(
                   color: headTextPrimary,
                              fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                              fontSize: 14,
                 letterSpacing: 1             
                ),
            autofocus: false,
              controller: controller,
              onSaved: onSaved,
              onChanged: onChanged,
              keyboardType: keyboardType,
              obscureText: obsecure,
    //Call the validator
              validator: (value) => password(texteditingcontroller.text = value),

  decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: backColorPrimary,width: 1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: greenPrimary,width: 1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
                ),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: backColorPrimary,
                hintText: hintText,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: hintexts,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular'
                )
              ),

    ]
    )
    )
```

Comment: i do not have any errors in this project but if i have one android studio does not tell me till i  run the project do u read me?